# How to store for loop iterations to a new data set

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmP2U.png)

**My code:**

```
for video in most_disliked:
    df1 = video['id'],video['statistics']
    print(df1)
```

**Output:**

```
('bvyTxpY9qJM', {'viewCount': '145', 'likeCount': '3', 'dislikeCount': '0', 'favoriteCount': '0', 'commentCount': '0'})
('gShHA7BZNCw', {'viewCount': '36', 'likeCount': '3', 'dislikeCount': '0', 'favoriteCount': '0', 'commentCount': '0'})
('q7gxl8RJEv4', {'viewCount': '11', 'likeCount': '2', 'dislikeCount': '0', 'favoriteCount': '0', 'commentCount': '1'})
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Videoid       viewcount   likecount   dislikecount  favouritecount  commentcount
bvyTxpY9qJM      145         3           0                0             0
gShHA7BZNCw       36         3           0                0             0
q7gxl8RJEv4       11         2           0                0             1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with a [Tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools available to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

`df1 = video['id'],video['statistics']` creates a tuple of two elements `video['id']` and `video['statistics']`.

To create a dataframe from the `most_disliked` list, you can use this example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'Videoid': video['id'], **video['statistics']} for video in most_disliked])
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
       Videoid viewCount likeCount dislikeCount favoriteCount commentCount
0  bvyTxpY9qJM       145         3            0             0            0
1  gShHA7BZNCw        36         3            0             0            0
2  q7gxl8RJEv4        11         2            0             0            1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [('bvyTxpY9qJM', {'viewCount': '145', 'likeCount': '3',
                        'dislikeCount': '0', 'favoriteCount': '0', 'commentCount': '0'}),
('gShHA7BZNCw', {'viewCount': '36', 'likeCount': '3',
                 'dislikeCount': '0', 'favoriteCount': '0', 'commentCount': '0'}),
('q7gxl8RJEv4', {'viewCount': '11', 'likeCount': '2',
                 'dislikeCount': '0', 'favoriteCount': '0', 'commentCount': '1'}),
]


most_liked = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'stat'])

df2 = pd.merge(most_liked['id'], most_liked['stat'].apply(pd.Series),
               left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output

```
            id viewCount likeCount dislikeCount favoriteCount commentCount
0  bvyTxpY9qJM       145         3            0             0            0
1  gShHA7BZNCw        36         3            0             0            0
2  q7gxl8RJEv4        11         2            0             0            1
```